# Can this circuit limit power surges?

Tags: relay, protection, surge-protection, varistor, mov

This circuit I had created based on MOV and a relay, it principle is: if a surge comes the MOV would get activated and should turn the relay thus the surge should be redirected.

[image]

Notes:
Input is normal 220 VAC RMS

MOV is rated 275 VAC

Relay gets triggered by 20 mA (the input is 120 V RMS)

Diode isn't rated it is just a high voltage one (above 1000 V).

Comment: What surge? What relay -- in particular turn-on delay time?

Comment: Please look up the length of a surge and compare that with the turn-on time of the relay.

Comment: I think I miss written it but I mean a long issue, like when a spark hits but can take 30 secs to settle and be stable

Comment: And how does whatever is to the output react to that before the relay triggers? How does the MOV feel after 30 seconds?

Comment: assume that relay do takes 50 ms to trigger, the Output would already be protected via MOVs and Fuses so it should be effective isn't it?

Comment: 50ms is 2.5 cycles of mains; are you sure this is even a "surge" (see IEC 61000-4-5, ITU-T K.21, etc.) so much as a high-line or swell condition? Or I'd suspect automotive load dump (e.g. ISO 7637-2) but the source is clearly given as AC.

Comment: With D5 & D1 both connected in the same direction, no matter what the MOV does the relay will never switch on.

Comment: @TimWilliams as I had stated mate, I may miss written it but the kind of surge that can last even more than 30seconds(issue that happens in cheap generators and hot weather makes them somehow go instead of 220VAC go up to 350VAC)

Comment: @brhans why not? it is just a half bridge rectifier

Comment: FYI, words have particular meaning in particular fields. EEs use "surge" to mean a one-time transient event superimposed on the line, duration a mere fraction of a second, and typically tens of microseconds at that.  Mains voltage is alternating; a surge is not. (At least unqualified. A ringing waveform might be called a surge, with a specifier ("ringing surge"), but is more often called a "burst".)  A modification of mains voltage is not a surge, but there is a word for that: "swell". Unfortunately we cannot read minds, so anything you have not written here, is unknown to us.

Comment: Also, this is an EE-design oriented Stack; it's not clear what merit you're after with your circuit, as the engineering problem of "cheap generators" is a long-solved one: buy a non-cheap generator that doesn't do that!  Whether that cost is due to the addition of such a protective circuit, or its need is avoided entirely due to better overall design, I suppose it's still a possibility.

Comment: @HazardousVoltage when D5 is forward-biased, what's the voltage drop across it? Maybe 1V? Since D5 is in parallel with D1, R1 & the relay, what's the voltage across those 3? Also 1V. So that's never going to turn the relay on. If one of the diodes was flipped around you'd have a different situation.